# What is wrong with my relative path?

Tags: c#, excel, relative-path

Hey so I am trying to access a excel file using a relative path because the application will be run on different computers so the path will not always be the same. right now I am doing something like this:

```
string exdestination = ".\\..\\..\\..\\Files";
string difDestination = Path.Combine(exdestination, "CATTII." + exTable + "-diff.xls");
//string difDestination = @"C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TranslatorHelper\Files\CATTII.en-US-diff.xls";
```

The last line is a commented line showing the path it should be. However I keep getting the error: Microsoft Office Excel cannot access the file 'C:\Files'. There are several possible reasons:

• The file name or path does not exist.
• The file is being used by another program.
• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: WHat is your current directory when you execute this code? Hint Environment.CurrentDirectory

Comment: "C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\TranslatorHelper\\TranslatorHelper\\bin\\Debug"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the path is relative to your program executable, then use [Application.StartupPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx) as the basis for your path. (You can't rely on the current directory necessarily being the path your exe is in; it can be set differently when running the program if the caller wishes, it can be changed by various system operations such as if you let the user browse with file/open dialogs, etc)

You need to remove the exe name from the end of this path, as in:

```
string folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath);
```

To go up 3 folders above that you can Combine a nasty relative path like "..\..\.." or just strip 3 folders off the folder:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(folder);
```

Then you need to add the rest of your path:

```
folder = Path.Combine(folder, "Files");
string difDestination = Path.Combine(folder, "CATTII." + exTable + "-diff.xls");
```

For extra credit you can add some error handling for coping with your executable not being 3+ folders deep, or the destination folder not being found, etc.

Comment: had to change the loop to i<2 but otherwise it works great, thanks

Comment: In that case you probably had one too many ".." in your original code :-)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is better to use a fixed subdirectory relative to a well known folder.

After you install your application in another computer you could retrieve your file using a base folder (Like MyDocuments of the current user or C:\ProgramData) and add a subfolder for your application data files.

```
 // This will be on your machine C:\ProgramData
 string baseDocs = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);

 // This will point to a subfolder named "TranslatorHelper" inside the ProgramData common folder
 string difDestination = Path.Combine(baseDocs, "TranslatorHelper", "CATTII." + exTable + "-diff.xls");
```

In the [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enum there are numerous well known folder and you can use the method above to reach the location where you have put the file

Answer (score 0):

I believe the PATH class will handle single slashes (and double slashes in either way // or \ - in the path string).   But I think you need two dots to start with, not just one.

..\   - up one folder

.      - this folder

You can test you have the right path by using the string you create to WRITE a new file and see where it ends up.